# VS Watch Window - any way to show all fields/properties in the single list?

Tags: visual-studio

VS Watch Window - is there any way to show all fields/properties in the single list (including all base classes, without need to browse all base classes and find necessary property there)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't but you can write your own debuggerVisualiazer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx